# Error showing while running a Container class program

Tags: c++

`Garden` contains *n* apple trees. Every apple tree can be characterized as follows: the harvest of the first year year, increase for every year past, and law according which the number of apples increase every year. The law uses two coefficients `coef1` and `coef2`. The law is common for all the apple trees, but coefficients may differ. You have to:
a) Find out the number of grown apples for every apple tree for the period of years. The number of years
is either entered from keyboard or defined as a constant value;
b) Find out the number of grown apples for every apple tree for the specific year;
c) Form new garden from the apple trees that have grown the number of apples during the period of years
not less than a defined value. The values of numbers of apples and period of years can be either
defined as constants or entered form keyboard.
This is just an initial part and giving errors:

> Warning   3   warning C4183: 'Print': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'    c:\users\kumar anubhav\documents\garden\atree.h 11  1   garden
>
> Warning   6   warning C4183: 'Print': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'    c:\users\kumar anubhav\documents\garden\atree.h 11  1   garden
>       9   IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands
>               operand types are: std::ostream << std::string  c:\Users\kumar anubhav\Documents\garden\Source.cpp  42  6   garden
>
> Error 2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\kumar anubhav\documents\garden\atree.h 11  1   garden
>
> Error 5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\kumar anubhav\documents\garden\atree.h 11  1   garden
>
> Error 7   error C2556: 'std::string Atree::Print(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int Atree::Print(void)'   c:\users\kumar anubhav\documents\garden\atree.cpp   9   1   garden
>
> Error 8   error C2371: 'Atree::Print' : redefinition; different basic types   c:\users\kumar anubhav\documents\garden\atree.cpp   9   1   garden
>
> Error 1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Print'   c:\users\kumar anubhav\documents\garden\atree.h 11  1   garden
>
> Error 4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Print'   c:\users\kumar anubhav\documents\garden\atree.h 11  1   garden

```
class Atree
{
private:
int year, increa;
int coef1, coef2;
 public:
Atree(): year(0), increa(16), coef1(1), coef2(2) { }
Atree(int year, int increa, int coef1, int coef2):
 year(year), increa(increa), coef1(coef1), coef2(coef2) { }
 string Print();
};


#include "Atree.h"
 #include <sstream>
 #include <iomanip>
 using namespace std;
//------------------------------------------------------------
 // Writes data into a line
 string Atree::Print()
 {
stringstream sr;
sr << setw(6) << coef1 << setw(6) << coef2
 << setw(5) << year << setw(7) << increa ;
return sr.str();
 }
#pragma once
//------------------------------------------------------------
#include "Atree.h"
class Garden
{
public:
static const int CMaxi = 100;
 private:
Atree Atrees[CMaxi];
int n;
 public:
Garden():n(0) { }
Atree Get(int i) { return Atrees[i]; }
int Get() { return n; }
void Set(Atree ob) { Atrees[n++] = ob; }
};
//------------------------------------------------------------
#include "Garden.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
//------------------------------------------------------------
const char Cu1[]="U1.txt";
//------------------------------------------------------------
void Read(Garden & Gard, const char fv []);
void Print(Garden & Gard);
//------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
 Garden Gard;
 Read(Gard, Cu1);
 Print(Gard);
 return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------
// Reads data from the file fv
void Read(Garden & Gard, const char fv [])
{
    ifstream fd(fv);
 int n;
 fd >> n;
 int coef1, coef2, year, increa;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 fd >> coef1 >> coef2 >> year >> increa;
 Gard.Set(Atree(year, increa, coef1, coef2));
 }
 fd.close();
 }
//------------------------------------------------------------
// Prints the data of object Gard
 void Print(Garden & Gard)
 {
 cout << " Information on apple trees\n";
 cout << " Coef1 coef2 year increa\n";
 for (int i = 0; i < Gard.Get(); i++)
cout << Gard.Get(i).Print() << endl;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This question is quite messy. You should try to clean it up and be specific about what your problem is. You don't need to paste your entire homework assignment in as the problem only seems to be that your code isn't compiling. You should always try to reduce your question to a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and often by doing so you will uncover the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the declaration of `Atree`, you have declared a method called `Print` which returns a `string`. The compiler doesn't know what a `string` is, and unlike the language C it can't just default the return type to `int`. You probably mean to use `std::string` and thus write:

```
class Atree
{
std::string Print();
};
```

You may need to `#include <string>` beforehand.

The compiler is also complaining because your definition of `Atree::Print`'s return type differs. Here it knows you are trying to use `std::string` because you have brought the `std` namespace in to context with the `using` keyword:

```
using namespace std;
string Atree::Print()
{
}
```

The compiler knows you wish to return a `std::string`, but this differs from the `Atree::Print` declaration, in which the compiler assumes you are trying to return an `int`.

You should avoid `using namespace std`. Doing so would've just given you errors about the compiler not knowing what a `string` is which would've (hopefully) made it easier to solve.

Comment: Please help as i m new but tried a lot to finish this with the help of notes....errors are still coming...I am using VS 2012